# Concatenated SQL fields in selector and/or custom PXDimension

Tags: acumatica

We have a set of BLC/DAC for a customization that has multiple tables with the given relationship

Table1 - T1ID (int-autoincrement), T1CD (char-substitute key)

Table2 - T2ID (int-autoincrement), T2CD (char-subsitute key), T1ID (reference to T1ID)

where the records in Table2 are unique for each given T1ID selected.

The initial design specification was for the users to select first the Table1 value, then the Table2 value (UsrTable1Value, UsrTable2Value respectively) in the data entry screens.

The users have recently asked if it's possible to combine these into one field simular to a Dimension selector so that there is one field resulting in "Table1-Table2" stored as T2ID.

My first thought was to simply create a subclassed dac with a concatenated property for T1CD-T2CD and base the substitute key off that however performance is a problem when that is done (1.6 million records). The delay is in the framwork side as it appears it processes the entire recordset when generating the concatenated substitute key.

Based on that I thought perhaps instead to simply generate a PXDimension configuration for this however I can't find any reference to make Dimension 2 rely on the value of Dimension 1.

I know i could always create a view that does this but i'd prefer to keep it within the framework if possible.

That basically brings me to two questions

1) Outside of a view, is there way to concatenate fields in the BQL so the lifting is done on the SQL and not with a calculated property?

2) Does anyone have or know of a sample of custom Dimensions where the values in level 2 depend on the value in level 1?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have not tried it but have you looked into PXDBCalced for performing SQL expressions?  Example: [PXDBCalced(typeof(Substring<finPeriodID, CS.int1, CS.int4>), typeof(string))] This might help you with question #1

Comment: I don't think there is a concatenate type to be used with this.   I'll have to dig into PXData to see if there is though..   Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You could also look into creating your own concatenate type by looking at Substring<> or other similar calls.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, dimension selectors are designed to work only with Segmented Keys and won't be able to handle values from multiple tables. In theory, it can be possible to populate segment popup from different tables within a custom DimentionSelectorAttribute. However, this will additionally require to store each T1ID/T2ID pair in a separate table with some other column declared as a key (same concept used in the Sub table to store sub accounts: SubID is a key and SubCD stores values composed from multiple segments).

My personal opinion, the effort is just not worth it. Going one step further, I would check with the customer on how they expect navigation buttons (first, prev, next, last) to work with their segmented input control? If following standard Acumatica UI design with separate input created for every key field, no additional effort is needed to properly handle both data entry and navigation.

Comment: I agree with that as well.  Fortunately for this there is no navigation needed.  This would be for supporting information in other detail lines (such as sales order lines) but the extra effort involved regardless doesn't justify the needs IMHO.    If I get time i might look at the DimensionSelectorAttribute even if I have to store it in a separate table.  I also could just create the pre-concatenated value and store that in the physical table then simply use a different selector.   They'd be forced to pick the predefined combination but I don't see that being a problem.